# Query conditional case for effective dating

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm building SQL and I need to filter to get the greatest (MAX) effective dated row and the lowest `PRIORITY` (MIN) number, but **only** for `VENDOR_ID`'s that have more than 1 MAX effective dated row. For `VENDOR_ID`'s where there is only 1 MAX effective dated row, then I want to retrieve that row, regardless of whether it is the `MIN PRIORITY` number.

Here is my current SQL - however it is excluding rows (that I want included) where there is a `VENDOR_ID` with a single MAX Effective dated row, **AND** it it not the `MIN PRIORITY` for that `VENDOR_ID`.

```
SELECT A.VENDOR_ID, *
  FROM PS_VENDOR A
  INNER JOIN HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB B ON B.EMPLID = A.VNDR_FIELD_C30_B
  WHERE A.VNDR_FIELD_C30_B <> ''
  AND B.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A_ED 
        WHERE B.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
          AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10))

  AND B.PRIORITY = 
     (SELECT MIN(AA.PRIORITY) FROM HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB AA
      WHERE B.EMPLID = AA.EMPLID)
```

**SAMPLE DATA:**

DATA IN PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB that should return a single row in above query, but is not because the greatest (single) effective dated row is not the MIN Priority (Bottom row, 2016-11-26 date):

```
VENDOR_ID   EFFDT                         PRIORITY
12345       1998-09-01 00:00:00.000       300
12345       2005-08-05 00:00:00.000       300
12345       2006-11-30 00:00:00.000       300
12345       2006-11-30 00:00:00.000       310
12345       2006-12-11 00:00:00.000       300
12345       2006-12-11 00:00:00.000       310
12345       2013-03-22 00:00:00.000       300
12345       2013-03-22 00:00:00.000       310
12345       2014-08-01 00:00:00.000       300
12345       2014-08-01 00:00:00.000       310
12345       2016-11-26 00:00:00.000       999
```

**EDIT 2:**

Below is an example for 2 VENDOR_ID's. VENDOR_ID 45678 has 2 MAX Effective Dated rows (2018-08-16), whereas VENDOR_ID has only 1 MAX Effective Dated row.

```
VENDOR_ID   EFFDT                     PRIORITY
45678       2018-08-16 00:00:00.000   2
45678       2018-08-16 00:00:00.000   999
12345       1998-09-01 00:00:00.000   300
12345       2005-08-05 00:00:00.000   300
12345       2006-11-30 00:00:00.000   300
12345       2006-11-30 00:00:00.000   310
12345       2006-12-11 00:00:00.000   300
12345       2006-12-11 00:00:00.000   310
12345       2013-03-22 00:00:00.000   300
12345       2013-03-22 00:00:00.000   310
12345       2014-08-01 00:00:00.000   300
12345       2014-08-01 00:00:00.000   310
12345       2016-11-26 00:00:00.000   999
```

Based on what I would like to do, my expected output for these 2 VENDOR_ID's would be the following:

```
   VENDOR_ID      EFFDT                       PRIORITY
   45678          2018-08-16 00:00:00.000     2
   12345          2016-11-26 00:00:00.000     999
```

In the case where we have more than 1 MAX effective dated row for a VENDOR_ID then I also want to apply the MIN(PRIORITY) logic above. Otherwise, in cases where there is a single MAX Effective dated row, then I don't want to apply the MIN(PRIORTY) logic. Hope that makes sense.

**EDIT 3:**

Entire SQL script with the INSERT I am doing, where the SELECT query above is being used as the basis for the INSERT. I want to be able to insert the hardcoded date, but still use the above logic:

```
INSERT PS_VNDR_BANK_ACCT (SETID, VENDOR_ID, VNDR_LOC, EFFDT, BANK_ACCT_SEQ_NBR, DESCR, DEFAULT_IND, BANK_ID_QUAL, BNK_ID_NBR, BRANCH_ID, BANK_ACCT_TYPE, CHECK_DIGIT, DFI_ID_QUAL, DFI_ID_NUM,
BENEFICIARY_BANK, BENEF_BRANCH_AC, BENEF_BRANCH, BENEF_BRANCH_AC, COUNTRY, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, ADDRESS4, CITY, NUM1, NUM2, HOUSE_TYPE, ADDR_FIELD1, ADDR_FIELD2, ADDR_FIELD3, COUNTY,
STATE, POSTAL, GEO_CODE, IN_CITY_LIMIT, COUNTRY_CODE, PHONE, EXTENSION, FAX, IBAN_CHECK_DIGIT, IBAN_ID, BANK_ACCOUNT_NUM

  SELECT 'SHARE', VENDOR_ID, '000001', '2019-03-01 00:00:00.000', '1', '', 'Y', '001', '88885', '', '03', '', '01', B.BANK_CD, 'Test Bank', '', '','',
  'USA', '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','', B.ACCOUNT_NUM
  FROM PS_VENDOR A
  INNER JOIN HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB B ON B.EMPLID = A.VNDR_FIELD_C30_B
  WHERE A.VNDR_FIELD_C30_B <> ''
  AND B.EFFDT = 
        (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A_ED 
        WHERE B.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
          AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10))

  AND B.PRIORITY = 
     (SELECT MIN(AA.PRIORITY) FROM HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB AA
      WHERE B.EMPLID = AA.EMPLID)
```

Comment: Questions like these are best answered if we can see some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Edited the post with sample data

Comment: OK.  Show us the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: Edited post again.

Comment: @RobertHarvey any suggestions?

Comment: It's going to be something along the lines of HAVING COUNT > 1

Comment: Yes I tried that but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need simple aggregation

```
 select VENDOR_ID   ,max(EFFDT),min(PRIORITY)
 from table_name group by VENDOR_ID
```

Comment: The SELECT query is going to be used as the basis for an INSERT command, and I want to insert a hardcoded EFFDT, so I don't think I can use the above aggregate functions within the SELECT clause....Is there a way to apply logic in the WHERE clause that will accomplish this?

Comment: @Nick from your sample data this query will generate your expected output

Comment: I want to use the SELECT as the basis of an INSERT; I edited the post to show the entire INSERT code with the SELECT query contain in it, you'll see I am trying to insert a hardcoded EFFDT from the SELECT, so I'm not sure you solution will work, or if it could be modified

Comment: any suggestions? I tried unioning the query into 2 select statements, and then put reverse logic on the one, however that does not give me the expected row totals.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add `EFFDT` as part of the Subquery on `B.PRIORITY` , where the effective date for the joined DIR_DEP_DISTRIB table is equal to the effective date on the PRIORITY sub query.

```
SELECT A.VNDR_FIELD_C30_B,    -- <-- I added this for debugging purposes
         'SHARE', VENDOR_ID, '000001', '2019-03-01 00:00:00.000', '1', '', 'Y', '001', '022000046', '', '03', '', '01', COALESCE(B.BANK_CD,'<No Match>'), 'Test Bank', '', '','',
         'USA', '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','', COALESCE(B.ACCOUNT_NUM,'<No Match>')
  FROM PS_VENDOR A
  INNER JOIN HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB B 
          ON B.EMPLID = A.VNDR_FIELD_C30_B  -- Moved the EFFDT and PRIORITY lines here from out of the WHERE clause, so I can do a proper LEFT JOIN
         AND B.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB A_ED 
                        WHERE B.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID
                          AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10) )
         AND B.PRIORITY = (SELECT MIN(AA.PRIORITY) FROM HRDEV01_FOR_BUDGET_MODULE.HRDEV92B.dbo.PS_DIR_DEP_DISTRIB AA
                           WHERE B.EMPLID = AA.EMPLID
                             AND B.EFFDT = AA.EFFDT)   -- Min Priority FOR A GIVEN EFFDT 
  WHERE A.VNDR_FIELD_C30_B <> ''
```